# Where is the BNF for the shader language used in WebGL?

Tags: fragment-shader, vertex-shader, webgl2

I'm having trouble locating the exact specification of the grammar for the WebGL2 shader language.  I see references that it is "based on" version 3 of the Open GL Shader language -- but it is obviously not exactly that since there are missing keywords in the Open GL version.  Where is the precise syntax of the shader language specified for the current version of WebGL supported on modern browsers?

For example [this spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf) specifically disallows the keyword "attribute" which is used in WebGL vertex shaders.  Where is the correct BNF grammar specified?

Comment: WebGL supports different GLSL version, so you define which version you want to use using `#version`. Which version did you specify there?

Comment: where would i find the grammar spec for any recent supported version?

Comment: GLSL 3.00 ES is supported, and if you define it as such using `#version 300 es` then you use `in` and `out` instead of `attribute` and `varying`. I asked the question to figure out for what configuration you are able to uses GLSL 3 ES and on the same time being allowed to use `attribute`. Knowing that I could explain you why that’s the case, that’s why I’m asking what version you specified in the shader.

Comment: [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php#specs3) corresponding to [OpenGL ES 3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) and [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The spec for WebGL2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) points to the specs for [GLSL ES 3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf) which contains the grammar in section 9.

The WebGL2 spec also points to [the spec for WebGL1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) which points to the spec for [GLSL ES 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf) which also happens to have its grammar in section 9.

Comment: thanks.  I was confused because examples of glsl for webgl I saw all include `attribute` and `varying` keyword and those have been omitted in glsl 3 in favor of `in` and `out` even though the spec claims that code written for older version should work for version 3 "without modification".

Comment: code does work `without modification`. you have to put `#version 300 es` at the top of your shader to enable GLSL ES 3.0. If you don't add that modification, if you just leave the 1.0 shaders unmodified then they get compiled as GLES ES 1.0 with `varying` and `attribute`